# J8583 message without bitmap

Tags: java, bitmap, iso8583

It's possible send a j8583 IsoMessage without bitmap field?

I need create a short message for authentication, but not should have bitmap.

Thanks

Comment: You can implement your own protocol at the terminal and server side. If you are planning to use standard hosts you should follow the host specification messages rules.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create an `IsoMessage` without a bitmap. Even for auth you should include a bitmap.

However, if you're required to omit a bitmap, you can create the message as a byte array and "cut out" the bitmap. For example if you're encoding text messages and don't have an ISO header, write the first 4 bytes of the buffer, and then the rest of the buffer starting at position 20 if you only have a primary bitmap, or position 36 if you have a secondary bitmap.

If the reply has no bitmap, the message factory won't be able to parse it, since the bitmap is essential to know what fields are included in the response.

Answer (score 0):

set ISOBasePackager.emitBitMap to false

Comment: Thanks, but I am using J8583 not JPOS